# Unity Argument Null Exception with Serialized Objects

Tags: unity-game-engine, serialization, null

I have been getting this persistent exception when working with serialized objects in the inspector. I have done sufficient debugging and null checks to nail it down to how the unity editor handles the inspector (onGUI and such), but I don’t really understand why the exception occurs/how to go about fixing it. Here is the code:

Serialized object class:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class QObj{

  public string myStr;

}
```

Monobehaviour:

```
public class QBehaviour: MonoBehaviour
{

  public QObj[] objArr;

}
```

and here is the exception trace:

```
Parameter name: _unity_self

UnityEditor.UIElements.Bindings.SerializedObjectList.get_Count () (at <8ad9ecbe25e14b10b6dde783af6e4aa2>:0)

UnityEditor.UIElements.Bindings.EditorListViewController.GetItemsCount () (at <8ad9ecbe25e14b10b6dde783af6e4aa2>:0)

UnityEngine.UIElements.VerticalVirtualizationController`1[T].get_firstVisibleIndex () (at <e66f217a64a747d48b478f0d70978704>:0)

UnityEngine.UIElements.DynamicHeightVirtualizationController`1[T].Fill () (at <e66f217a64a747d48b478f0d70978704>:0)

UnityEngine.UIElements.VisualElement+SimpleScheduledItem.PerformTimerUpdate (UnityEngine.UIElements.TimerState state) (at <e66f217a64a747d48b478f0d70978704>:0)

UnityEngine.UIElements.TimerEventScheduler.UpdateScheduledEvents () (at <e66f217a64a747d48b478f0d70978704>:0)

UnityEngine.UIElements.UIElementsUtility.UnityEngine.UIElements.IUIElementsUtility.UpdateSchedulers () (at <e66f217a64a747d48b478f0d70978704>:0)

UnityEngine.UIElements.UIEventRegistration.UpdateSchedulers () (at <e66f217a64a747d48b478f0d70978704>:0)

UnityEditor.RetainedMode.UpdateSchedulers () (at <8ad9ecbe25e14b10b6dde783af6e4aa2>:0)
```

For me at least, the error will only begin happening if I change the size of the objArr to nonzero, then run the program. The error will then repeat itself seemingly every frame, even after the run is stopped. It is only after you recompile the monobehaviour that the exception stops being raised. Any insight is appreciated!!!

Comment: I'm afraid that I can't reproduce the error. If I make a script with both of your provided snippets I can create an array of any length and fill it as intended. Running the program does not result in any errors or warnings. There might be something different at play for you.

Comment: con you confirm that your scripts are called correctly matching the class name .. including the casing?